How to push metrics to Prometheus Pushgateway in Spring Boot 3?
I want to push metrics to Prometheus PushGateway from my Spring Boot application.
In Spring Boot Actuator documentation, I read that:

The Prometheus Pushgateway only works with the deprecated Prometheus simpleclient for now, until the Prometheus 1.x client adds support for it. To switch to the simpleclient, remove io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus from your project and add io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus-simpleclient instead.
...

So I added two dependencies to my project:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus-simpleclient</artifactId>
    <version>${micrometer-registry-prometheus.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleclient_pushgateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.16.0</version>
</dependency>

I also added management.prometheus.metrics.export.pushgateway.enabled: true to my application.properties
I'm confused about what I'm supposed to do next, because documentation is not explaning how do I actually initialize PushGateway and how to actually push metrics.
I tried to initialize my PushGateway like this:
public static PushGateway PROMETHEUS_PUSH_GATEWAY = new PushGateway(prometheusPushGatewayAddress);

Then the push() method requires CollectorRegistry. I tried creating it like that:
private final CollectorRegistry prometheusMeterRegistry = new CollectorRegistry();

Now when I'm trying to register my Counter, it expects not CollectorRegistry, but MeterRegistry:
public void incrementCleanOrphanOrderDraftsJobTimeoutMetric() {
        Counter.builder("order_service.cronjob.clean_orphan_order_drafts.timeouts.total")
            .description("Represents how many times the CleanOrphanOrderDraftsJob cronjob failed with timeout")
            .register(prometheusMeterRegistry) <-- error here
            .increment();
    }

This is where I'm stuck at the moment.
